# Transforming a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a Data Frame in R that looks like this with about 7k rows.

```
Customer ID  Test_Control DF    Purchase 
1112223333      test      ab     False  
2222223333      Control   ab     False
3332223333      Control   ab     True
4442223333      test      ab     False
```

About the data:

- All of the Customer_ID's are unique.
- The "Purchase" columns are either True or false
- The "Test_Control" column is either "test" or "Control"
- The DF column alway has "ab"

I need to transform it to look like this:

```
Test     Control
0        1
0        1
1        0 
0        1
```

About the transformation:

- The Test_control column should be separated into two columns based off if it is Test or Control
- If the Purchase column it "False" it should be a 0 for both the "test" and "control" column
- If the Purchase column is 'True' then a "1" should go into either the "test" or "control" column. For example, If the "test_control" column is test then the 1 would go in the "test" column.

Essentially, I am prepping this to fo a t.test().

Comment: I'm a little confused: the data you provide doesn't map to the example you want based on your own rules. Is it supposed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the reshape2 library, one can maintain links to the original data:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(Customer.ID = c(1112223333, 2222223333, 3332223333, 4442223333),
                 Test_Control = c("test", "Control", "Control", "test"),
                 DF = rep("ab", 4),
                 Purchase = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))
#Add dummy column with the desire result    
df$result<-1
#cast the data frame
dcast(df, Customer.ID + Purchase + DF ~ Test_Control, fill=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifelse` for this. For each variable, it checks whether `Purchase` is false, in which case it assigns a value of 0. Otherwise, it checks the value of `Test_Control` to determine whether to assign a 1 or a 0.

```
df <- data.frame(Customer.ID = c(1112223333, 2222223333, 3332223333, 4442223333),
                 Test_Control = c("test", "Control", "Control", "test"),
                 DF = rep("ab", 4),
                 Purchase = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))

df$Test <- ifelse(!df$Purchase, 0, ifelse(df$Test_Control=="test", 1, 0))
df$Control <- ifelse(!df$Purchase, 0, ifelse(df$Test_Control=="Control", 1, 0))
```